# sfdx force:package:version:create gave me erros

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

Now, I'm creating package version with community, custom object, custom tab, custom application but can't create version with the following errors. How can I solve it?

```
test-unlocked-package git:(master) ✗ sfdx force:package:version:create -p openaccount -d unlocked-core -k test1234 --wait 10 -f config/project-scratch-def.json
Request in progress. Sleeping 30 seconds. Will wait a total of 600 more seconds before timing out. Current Status='Initializing'
Request in progress. Sleeping 30 seconds. Will wait a total of 570 more seconds before timing out. Current Status='Verifying metadata'
Request in progress. Sleeping 30 seconds. Will wait a total of 540 more seconds before timing out. Current Status='Verifying metadata'
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  AppSwitcher: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 421222923-158080 (442557440),cbUnlocked_Package: Network not found for the CustomBrand : cbUnlocked_Package,Unlocked Package: In field: welcomeEmailTemplate - no EmailTemplate named unfiled$public/CommunityWelcomeEmailTemplate found,Default_Unlocked Package: 利用者には少なくとも 1 つの条件が必要です。,Default_Navigation: In field: Network - no Network named Unlocked Package found,Unlocked_Package: In field: Name - no Network named Unlocked Package found,Unlocked_Package1: No Network named Unlocked Package found, needed to associate this Site Unlocked_Package1, which is 0DM0l0000008SmF,Unlocked_Package1: In field: Network - no Network named Unlocked Package found
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/318305

As of now(**v50.0**), **communities are not supported with the Unlocked Packages**.

You can check the coverage for metadata elements here - [Metadata Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50)

However, you can deploy(and publish) the communities through the MDAPI(Metadata API). If you see the [E-Bikes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc) project on github. It shows how they've deployed communities using **ExperienceBundle Metadata API**.

[Official document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5) - for deploying communities through MDAPI