# Communities error when building new package version for code coverage

Tags: salesforcedx, code-coverage, unlocked-package, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

I'm attempting to build a new version of a package by using the --codecoverage switch like so:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p myPackageName -w 100 -x --json --codecoverage --loglevel DEBUG
```

However, running this command gives me this error

```
"status": 1,
"name": "Error",
"message": "Communities: Chatter Community domain must be set prior to enabling Communities",
"exitCode": 1,
"commandName": "PackageVersionCreateCommand",
```

I have **Communities** as a feature in my scratch-org-def.json

```
"edition": "Enterprise",
"country": "US",
"features": [
    "API",
    "Communities",
    "LightningSalesConsole",
    "ExternalSharing",
    "MultiCurrency",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "StateAndCountryPicklist"
],
```

But removing this feature doesn't fix this version create error.  Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now(**v50.0**), **communities are not supported with the Unlocked Packages**.

You can check the coverage for metadata elements here - [Metadata Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50)

However, you can deploy(and publish) the communities through the MDAPI(Metadata API). If you see the [E-Bikes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc) project on github. It shows how they've deployed communities using **ExperienceBundle Metadata API**.

[Official document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5) - for deploying communities through MDAPI

Comment: Accepted.  Removing the reference to communities from the sfdx-project.json causes other errors though, that are unrelated to this,

Comment: Thanks for that Yar!